# Why are the buttons in my Python Tkinter Stone, Paper, Scissor app working erratically?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made the following code for a Stone, Paper and Scissor app in Python using Tkinter. When I run it, everything is fine except that the buttons work erratically. If I click a button, sometimes it gives a result and sometimes it doesn't. The code is given below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
a = ("Stone","Paper","Scissor")
window = tk.Tk()
playlabel = tk.Label(text = "This is an app to play Stone, Paper, Scissor.\nClick any one of the buttons to make your choice and the app will tell you its random choice and tell you wether you have won or lost.")
playlabel.pack()
def stonecommand ():
    if random.choice(a) == "Stone":
        slabel = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose Stone!")
        slabel.pack()
        if random.choice(a) == "Paper":
            slabel1 = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose paper!")
            slabel1.pack()
            if random.choice(a) == "Scissor":
                slabel2 = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose scissor!")
                slabel2.pack()

def scissorcommand ():
    if random.choice(a) == "Stone":
        scilabel = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose Stone")
        scilabel.pack()
        if random.choice(a) == "Paper":
            scilabel1 = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose paper!")
            scilabel1.pack()
            if random.choice(a) == "Scissor":
                scilabel2 = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose scissor!")
                scilabel2.pack()

def papercommand ():
    if random.choice(a) == "Stone":
        plabel = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose stone!")
        plabel.pack()
        if random.choice(a) == "Paper":
            plabel1 = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose chose paper!")
            plabel1.pack()
            if random.choice(a) == "Scissor":
                plabel2 = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose scissor!")
                plabel2.pack()

stonebutton = tk.Button(text = "Stone", width = 10, command = stonecommand)
paperbutton = tk.Button(text = "Paper", width = 10, command = papercommand)
scissorbutton = tk.Button(text = "Scissor", width = 10, command = scissorcommand)
stonebutton.pack()
paperbutton.pack()
scissorbutton.pack()
```

Please tell whether is it a problem in the code, because I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, it's because each "turn" is making multiple choices. You should be calling `random.choice(a)` once per function. Your functions should look something like this:

```
def stonecommand ():
    choice = random.choice(a)
    if choice == "Stone":
        slabel = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose Stone!")
        slabel.pack()
    elif choice == "Paper":
        slabel1 = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose paper!")
        slabel1.pack()
    else
        slabel2 = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose scissor!")
        slabel2.pack()
```

Also, you should probably create the label outside of these functions, and then modify it inside the function.

```
def stonecommand ():
    choice = random.choice(a)
    if choice == "Stone":
        resultlabel.configure(text = "Draw, because we both chose Stone!")
    elif choice == "Paper":
        resultlabel.configure(text = "You lost, because I chose paper!")
    else
        resultlabel.configure(text = "You won, because I chose scissor!")
...
stonebutton = tk.Button(text = "Stone", width = 10, command = stonecommand)
paperbutton = tk.Button(text = "Paper", width = 10, command = papercommand)
scissorbutton = tk.Button(text = "Scissor", width = 10, command = 
scissorcommand)
resultlabel = tk.Label(text="")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have used more than one 'if' statement in your app commands. Use 'elif' commands for the last two commands. I'll give you the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
a = ["Stone","Paper","Scissor"]
window = tk.Tk()

playlabel = tk.Label(text = "This is an app to play Stone, Paper, Scissor.\nClick any one of the buttons to make your choice and the app will tell you its random choice and tell you wether you have won or lost.")

playlabel.pack()

def stonecommand():
    if random.choice(a) == "Stone":
        slabel = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose Stone!")
        slabel.pack()
    elif random.choice(a) == "Paper":
            slabel1 = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose paper!")
            slabel1.pack()
    elif random.choice(a) == "Scissor":
                slabel2 = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose scissor!")
                slabel2.pack()

def scissorcommand ():
    if random.choice(a) == "Stone":
        scilabel = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose Stone")
        scilabel.pack()
    elif random.choice(a) == "Paper":
            scilabel1 = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose paper!")
            scilabel1.pack()
    elif random.choice(a) == "Scissor":
                scilabel2 = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose scissor!")
                scilabel2.pack()

def papercommand ():
    if random.choice(a) == "Stone":
        plabel = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose stone!")
        plabel.pack()
    elif random.choice(a) == "Paper":
            plabel1 = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose chose paper!")
            plabel1.pack()
    elif random.choice(a) == "Scissor":
                plabel2 = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose scissor!")
                plabel2.pack()

stonebutton = tk.Button(text = "Stone", width = 10, command = stonecommand)
paperbutton = tk.Button(text = "Paper", width = 10, command = papercommand)
scissorbutton = tk.Button(text = "Scissor", width = 10, command = scissorcommand)
stonebutton.pack()
paperbutton.pack()
scissorbutton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

***PS - elif means else if.***

I hope that this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bad indentation, check with same indentation and to use `elif` and `else`

```
def stonecommand ():
    if random.choice(a) == "Stone":
        slabel = tk.Label(text = "Draw, because we both chose Stone!")
        slabel.pack()
    elif random.choice(a) == "Paper":
        slabel1 = tk.Label(text = "You lost, because I chose paper!")
        slabel1.pack()
    else:
        slabel2 = tk.Label(text = "You won, because I chose scissor!")
        slabel2.pack()
```

same thing for the another functions.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you call `random.choice()` more than once and the subsequent `if` statements is not the same indentation level as the first one.

Actually you can `random.choice()` on the result instead:

```py
...
def stonecommand():
    result = random.choice((
        "Draw, because we both chose Stone!",
        "You lost, because I chose paper!",
        "You won, because I chose scissor!"
    ))
    resultlabel.config(text=result)

def scissorcommand():
    result = random.choice((
        "You lost, because I chose Stone",
        "You won, because I chose paper!",
        "Draw, because we both chose scissor!"
    ))
    resultlabel.config(text=result)

def papercommand():
    result = random.choice((
        "You won, because I chose stone!",
        "Draw, because we both chose chose paper!",
        "You lost, because I chose scissor!"
    ))
    resultlabel.config(text=result)

resultlabel = tk.Label(font="Arial 16 bold")
resultlabel.pack()
...
```